# Puppeteer to create Login with Facebook button

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, puppeteer, facebook-login

I'm trying to create an empty page and login with facebook button by puppeteer, but the button doesn't show up. I've tried in html file with the same javascript code and it works fine (It took 3-5 seconds for button to shown up)

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    // Add Facebook Login button
    let loginButton = document.createElement("fb:login-button");
    loginButton.setAttribute("scope", "public_profile,email");
    loginButton.setAttribute("onlogin", "checkLoginState()");

    // Add button to body
    let body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(loginButton);
  });
  await page.addScriptTag({
    content: () => {
      // Facebook Login Function
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: process.env.facebook_app_id_test,
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: "v8.0"
        });

        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };

      (function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
          fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");

      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

      function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }
    }
  });

  await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Facebook’s ToS generally forbid to use any such automation tools on their website UI, so what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @CBroe I'm trying to do integration testing for my facebook login api, I try to use puppeteer to retrieve facebook's access token. Is it possible to create a custom login with facebook button with puppeteer?

Comment: What exact method of rendering a login button you use should not matter. The Facebook app system isn’t really set up for that kind of automated testing though.